# Can I break up observational window in order to increase sample size?

Tags: t-test, statistical-power

I want to compare a tasks completed in the morning to tasks completed in the evening. The participants are given 4 hours to complete the tasks. I will do a t-test to compare the effectiveness of the tasks.

To increase my statistical power, I'm thinking about breaking up the 4 hour windows into 4 separate windows.  So, if there are 40 total assignments (20 morning and 20 evening), my sample size would go from 40 to 160.

Would that work? It feels like I'm cheating, but I don't know why.

Comment: If the tasks take four hour to complete, how will you choose which of the resulting four windows to assign the task to?

Comment: Well, we assign then a 4 hour window and they can complete the task anytime in that window they want to. The task takes anywhere from 5 minutes to 2 hours to complete. I would include all the hour windows into the analysis. The hours where they're not completing the tasks would show up as zeroes in the data.

Comment: Notice that if you do that, you're going to have four variables for each morning participant, and those four variables are *dependent* on one another, since only one can be non-zero.  This makes a paired t-test application invalid (very invalid).